# How to get column count in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I m using Cassandra DB.I want to know how to get count of column of particular columnFamily in cassandra

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using the Thrift API method, you should use one of the high level clients available here: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions

Most of them present a get_count() or multiget_count() method that you can use, and they have much nicer APIs.

Comment: +1 for suggesting high level clients instead of raw thrift. (nice to see you on SO thobbs :))

Comment: Also one problem with using Thrift directly is that each time the API changes you have to update your app. With a higher level client, it is likely that many of those changes will remain hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Thrift api method called "[get_count](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API#get_count)". More APIs documented on the Apache Cassandra API [wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API)